# How to set up Docker containers for Java Spring Boot and MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker

I cannot get my Docker container running a Java Spring Boot Api layer to communicate with my Docker container running a MySql database.

1) I created the MySql image as follows:

```
docker run -d 
--name aname-mysql 
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root 
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=db 
-e MYSQL_USER=root 
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD=root 
mysql:5.7
```

2) I built the Docker image for the Java Spring Boot app as follows:

```
./gradlew build docker -x test
```

3) I created the Docker container for the Java Spring Boot app as follows:

```
docker run -d 
-p 8080:8080 --name app-api 
--link aname-mysql:mysql 
-e DATABASE_HOST=aname-mysql 
-e DATABASE_PORT:3306 
-e DATABASE_NAME=db 
-e DATABASE_USER=root 
-e DATABASE_PASSWORD=root 
com.app/my.api
```

4) My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-Dspring.profiles.active=container", "-jar","/app.jar"]
```

5) My application-container.yml file looks like this

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    username: ${DATABASE_USER}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
      show_sql: true
```

After running these commands and then entering

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users
```

I get an error stating that the site refuses to connect and only the default browser error page is shown. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Your mysql container isn't exposing any ports so basically is inaccessible from the outside. Either expose port 3306 as an external port or create a single docker-compose file so that both containers share the network and so that you can reference them by their container name and don't need to externally expose the ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a docker-compose.yaml and put the following

```
version: '2'
services:
  database:
    container_name:db
    restart: always
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
  java:
    image: <YOUR JAVA IMAGE>
    links:
     - "database"
```

start services:

```
docker-compose up
```

try to connect to it through localhost:3306 from java
or get the ip of db container:

```
docker inspect db
```

look for the public ip then connect to it

Comment: How should my Dockerfile be changed to accommodate docker-compose.yml? Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to change anything in the Dockerfile, it should work like this

Comment: docker-compose up fails for me. The error message I received is ERROR: for c6a25cdaa43d_aname-mysql  Cannot start service database: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint aname-mysql.  I've tried deleting all images and containers and then starting over. There are no port conflicts from what I can tell. My steps are 1) delete images and containers (except for mysql and openjdk 2) ./gradlew build docker 3) docker-compose up. Then the aforementioned error appears. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: or just edit the database service to the following:
`image: mysql
     ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
`

Comment: database:
    container_name: aname-mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bgdb
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
  banking-api:
    image: com.abcd/my.api
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=database
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
      - DATABASE_NAME=bgdb
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306

Comment: No luck, and I'm following your instructions.

Comment: ok it might be problem with indent, so to fix this you can't copy paste the code from here, go to the section where it says docker-compose in this link then copy paste the code and change the wordpress image with your java  image: https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Put both applications into a docker compose and refer to each other by their docker names.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed a typo. Instead of DATABASE_PORT=3306, I used a colon. With this correction, the Java Spring Boot container is now linked to and working properly with the MySql container.